# How to animate transformed component between rerender?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation, react-beautiful-dnd

I am trying to animate my components after they are dropped into a new position. I use `react-beautiful-dnd` for drag and drop.

[sandbox example for this situation](https://codesandbox.io/s/vertical-list-with-multiple-drop-targets-tz2lq)

Here you can see, that when I drag one element from one list and drop to another list, that dropped item first drops to the last position of the list, and after that, it goes directly to the first position of the droppable list.
When dropping, it is dropped by using transition, but after pushing it to first position (here react does rerender), it only updates the view without animating (i know that it is normal behavior). I tried to add a transition to those elements, but that didn't help me.
Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: Found a normal demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/9z7qwmmr7r?from-embed), not sure where went wrong.

Comment: It is not my case. It doesn't push the dropped item into the first position of the list

Comment: I know, I mean by comparing those two you may find somewhere went wrong which I'm not sure by now.